# Hide ID number from url in php post

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I'm working on a local project of wordpress and I try to hide the post id from an url, I use this function to do a rewrite rule for a determinate url in my functions.php file:

```
function mycustomname_link_p($post_link, $post = 0) {
    foreach ($GLOBALS['array_p'] as $post_type) {
        if ($post->post_name === $post_type) {
            return home_url('nature' .'/'. 'posts'.'/'. $post->post_name .'/'. $post->ID);
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'mycustomname_link_p', 10, 2);

function mycustomname_rewrites_init_p(){
    #foreach ($GLOBALS['array'] as $post_type) {        
        add_rewrite_rule('nature/posts/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=persona_pubblica&p=$matches[2]', 'top');
    #}

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'mycustomname_rewrites_init_p');
```

So if I not use $post->ID the rewrite rule for the url doesn't work, i don't know how to hide the id number from the url, my url structure is this:
http://project.local/nature/posts/post_name/12/

Comment: This URL structure is also called the permalink structure. Have you looked at the Settings > Permalinks part of your site's dashboard?

Comment: Yes, i try but nothing happen, it's like when i apply the rule, this has the priority on all the other structure.